# Change width and height RegEx javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help me change string:

```
<img src="hello.jpg" alt="^__^" width="100" height="76" />
```

to

```
<img src="hello.jpg" alt="^__^" width="200" height="150" />
```

using regular expression.

New information::

I have a product item and in  stores information about different variables for this product

```
    <tr>
        <td><img src="_tmp/gesan/benzin/G3000H.jpg" alt="G3000H" width="100" height="76" /></td>
        <td>G3000H</td>
        <td>2.2 kv</td>
        <td>2.75 ka</td>
        <td>3,6</td>
        <td>1,3</td>
        <td>39,7кг</td>
        <td>2000 rub</td>
    </tr>
```

when you hover this  element a new PopUp menu appear with help of this javascript:

```
$("tr:gt(0)").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#ccc'});
    $(this).each(function(){
        var itemImage = this.cells[0].innerHTML;itemImage2 = itemImage.replace(/(width=")\d+("\W+height=")\d+/, '$1200$2150');
        var itemName = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
        var itemPowerkVa = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
        var itemPowerKVt = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
        $("body").append("<div id='tip'><div id='tipWrap'>"+ itemImage2 +"<h4>"+ loadContainerArr[0]+" "+ itemName +"</h4><ul><li>"+ itemPowerkVa +"</li><li>" + itemPowerKVt +"</li></ul></div></div>");
    });
    tipItem  = $("#tip");
    tipItem.show(); //Show tooltip
},function() {
    tipItem.hide(); //Hide tooltip
    $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
    tipItem.remove();
})
```

and i suppose in this situation it's better to use RegEx, than create a new Object

Comment: Why Regex? Since you are on the Client side, why not just use jQuery or something?

Comment: Please add some more information. More information => better answers.

Comment: **Felix Kling** - added new information (thanks for reply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use a regex:

```
str.replace(/(width=")\d+("\W+height=")\d+/, '$1200$2150');
```

Note that your `200` and `150` are part of "$1 **200** $2 **150**"

But I'll 2nd the other comments that say there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Why you want to use regex here ?

Just grab that `img` element with JS and change its CSS properties:

```
<img id="test" src="hello.jpg" alt="^__^" width="100" height="76" />


document.getElementById("test").style.width  = '200px';
document.getElementById("test").style.height = '150px';
```

Using regex all the time is not a good solution. It is one of that case.

Edit:

If you use `jQuery`, convert HTML string to an object:

```
var img = $('<img src="hello.jpg" alt="^__^" width="100" height="76" />');
img.attr('width', 200);
img.attr('height', 150);
```

Comment: Man, you see - i receive a string, not object -> that's why i need RegEx

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`/`mooTools`/etc ?

Comment: **hsz**, dude, thank you for your reply. You answer is very good, but i still need to get RegEx. I've thinked twice and suppose that creating new jQuery object from string is slower for performance, than get RegEx and replace 2 variables. I'm not a psychopathe about performance, but it's always better to do 1 thing good, than several things bad.

Comment: @Vovan: It might be unmeasurably slower, but it is the *right way* to do it. What are you doing with the string anyway? Inserting it in the DOM? Unfortunately you don't seem to want to give more information, so we cannot help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Look, there:

**pattern**: `/(.\*)(width=\"[0-9]+\")(.\*)(height=\"76\")(.\*)/smUi`

**replacement**: `$1width="200"$3height="150"$5`

U can use this with PHP:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data); // where the $data is the text with image
```

... or any other language :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

Create the `<div id='tip'>` from the beginning (and hide it initially) and only show and hide it (no need to create and destroy it every time):

```
<div id="tip" style="display:none">
    <div id="tipWrap">
        <img src="" alt="" width="200" height="150" />
        <h4></h4>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
$("tr:gt(0)").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
    var $tip = $('#tipWrap'),
        $tds = $(this).children(),
        $img = $(this).find('img'),
        itemName = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        itemPowerkVa = $tds.eq(2).text(),
        itemPowerKVt = $tds.eq(3).text();

    $tip.children('img').attr({
        src: $img.attr('src'),
        alt: $img.attr('alt')
    })
    .end().children('h4').text(loadContainerArr[0]+" "+ itemName)
    .end().children('ul').html("<li>"+ itemPowerkVa +"</li><li>" + itemPowerKVt +"</li>")
    .end().parent().show();
},function() {
    $('#tip').hide(); //Hide tooltip
    $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to recreate it without destroying